# Standalone accelerometers to track the movement of bow limbs

Tags: sensors

I'd like to track the movement of my bow limbs.

I think I can install a pair of accelerometers and analyze the logs to see what happens upon full draw and release.

Each accelerometer should be small enough to fit bow limb width.

Accelerometers should run on batteries because I want the setup to be as light as possible. They also should send logs remotely using some wireless protocol. Same reason.

I'm a software developer:

- the protocol that's used by accelerometers to send logs outside is not a major concern;
- building the device myself it's something I'd avoid.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a premade device to measure acceleration and transmit to a remote server or something similar? What type of communication are you looking at (e.g. Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, mobile data...)? If you could [edit] with that and any other relevant information, it might make your question more likely to get a helpful answer. Also keep in mind that [just asking for a device](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is discouraged — I'd suggest instead reworking your question if possible with the tips given in the link. Good luck!

Comment: A BLE MCU with an accelerometer is not an uncommon eval/demo board.  Hopefully you're not trying to actually use the accelerometer *for* tracking as that doesn't work - at best that can help bridge brief gaps in the data from some other tracking source.  So really, to have a practical question you'll need first to concentrate on the tracking solution.

Comment: I think that you are on the wrong site here. Why not try asking at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Mawg I think this could be on-topic here; it's just that we need more information to help out. If the issue is simply selecting the correct piece of hardware, it might not be relevant to this site (although if it's only asking about an accelerator component rather than a whole device, it [might be off-topic on Hardware Recommendations too](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255)). However, if the connectivity aspect is important (which I suspect it might be in this case) then at least some aspects could fit there.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks for editing. I think we need a little more info about your exact constraints. Perhaps consider also your power requirements (battery, etc), how long the device needs to run on power (days, weeks, hours?), more specific range (how many metres?). Possibly also consider the protocol you'd like to use (MQTT, HTTP?). And would you be open to building something yourself if no market device is available? As you can see, there's a lot of information you can add to make your question specific, so it'd be great if you [edit] that in.

Comment: @Aurora0001 It seems that the question focuses on the hardware part and not on the connectivity, "the protocol that's used by accelerometers to send logs outside is not a major concern" .

Comment: @Mawg https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ doesn't have necessary tags so, I think this question is not relevant to that site.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I mean, you can suggest solutions using any protocol that fits. It's the software part of the project. Being a software developer, I used many protocols and learning a new one is not a major concern.

Comment: No site has the necessary tags - until they are proposed. Which are you thinking of, other than accelerometer?  It's the bets site for your question though (just trying to help)

Comment: I would think that a more appropriate method would be to capture high speed video and then do a video analysis of the imagery showing bow pull and bow release. For example see this journal article [Computer-based video analysis of movement](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004951414605420)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the Internet of Things but rather about detailed application of accelerometers or other measuring techniques to a physical problem.